# get click location error

Tags: c#, click

i try to get mouse location, this code

```
intx[];

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x[0] = e.X;
        x[1] = e.Y;
    }
```

But a have error
"Object reference not set to an instance of the object". Help please. thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your array:

```
int[] x = new int[2];
```